# WPF Datepicker Control None option(WPF ToolKit)

Tags: wpftoolkit

How to provide an option to select No dates(None) in datepicker control?

Please help!!

Thanks 
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have actually installed the WPF Toolkit and tried it...

I found out that if you manually delete the text in the textbox part of the datepicker, then the `SelectedDate` is actually deleted. Optionally, you can add a button that deletes the `SelectedDate` directly.

### WPF code:

```
    <my:DatePicker Name="DatePicker1" Height="26"  xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" />
    <Button Name="btnDeleteDate" Height="26"  Width="90">Set no date</Button>
```

### Code behind (VB):

```
Private Sub btnDeleteDate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnDeleteDate.Click
    DatePicker1.SelectedDate = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you want the todays date not to be highlighted as grey, you can set `IsTodayHighlighted` to false.

It is still the "active date" though, which is a visible box around a date that is kind of a "cursor" that is the start point if you move around with the arrows on the keybord. This is not the same as `SelectedDate`, but the selected date is set immediately when you start to move it around.

Comment: Sorry, my original answer (*Try to set SelectionMode=None*) does not apply. I was only reading documentation somewhere. It was probably not the same control.. I have added a more complete answer here now.

Comment: I found out that the `SelectionMode` is only available on the **Calendar** control, which was described in the same article as the **DatePicker** control: http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx